# Oбъединение списков полученные перебором

Tags: python

Здраствуйте

Столкнулся с проблемой. Мне необходимо объединить 3 списка, полученные циклом for.
Проблема в том что я не знаю как дать каждому списку переменную для их объединения.
Тег href выдаёт мне 3 ссылки когда мне нужно только одна, это первая ссылка. Поэтому я хочу записать эти три ссылки в список и потом эти списки объединить, что бы получить первый элемент то есть нужную мне ссылку.

```
name_obj = soup.find("table",class_="wiki-content-table").find_all("a")
for item in name_obj: 
    item_text = item.text 
    item_url =  item.get("href") 
    sd = [item_url]
    print(sd)
```

На каждой итерации он мне выводит 3 ссылки, тогда как мне нужна только одна,это первая ссылка которую он мне выводит при итерации.

Comment: добавьте примеры того, что вы получаете и также пример в каком виде вы хотите получить

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите получать 3 раза, то не вызывайте это в цикле просто:

```
name_obj = soup.find("table",class_="wiki-content-table").find_all("a")

item_url =  name_obj[0].get("href")

for item in name_obj: 
    item_text = item.text 
    sd = [item_url]
    print(sd)
```